# Adobe Acrobat Forms Javascript or Adobe Extend Script

Tags: javascript, templates, adobe, acrobat, extendscript

I am wanting to create a print template for clients that allow them to update basic info on posters and flyers with out losing complete control over text formatting and design. My Idea was to make and pdf where the first page is a form where clients can enter the content to be updated, and the second page will be the design with empty text frames that their form entries will populate. I want to be able to style the the content that goes into these frames with specific type faces, font size, alignment ect. Is this possible, and if so is it achieved through the Adobe Forms javascript or Adobe ExtendScript?

Answer (score 0):

I've created many such "forms" for use as design templates. You'd use JavaScript for Acrobat and a combination of regular text fields and text fields that allow Rich Text. The formatting options for programmatically setting Rich Text values are quite limited though. You can't program everything that Acrobat can represent by formatting the Rich Text via the Properties toolbar or pasting into the field. For example, you can't set the vertical alignment to "middle" and you can't control the leading. It's best to create your mockups with these limitations in mind prior to trying to program the script.

Comment: Would you mind sharing one of your templates with me so that I can look under the hood to see the javascript works?

Comment: I'd love to but my client uses them as promotions so I can't. However, the JavaScript for Acrobat documentation has a couple of examples that show how to format text and add it to a field. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FField_properties.htm%23TOC_richValue1bc-40&rhtocid=_6_1_8_31_1_39